# Subspaces of topological spaces are compact

Tags: general-topology

I have the subspaces $K_{1}=((0,\frac{1}{2})× \{a\})∪([0,1]× \{b\})$ and $K_{2}=([0,1]×\{a\})∪((0,\frac{1}{2})×\{b\})$.

They are subspaces of the space X represented by $(\mathbb{R},\varepsilon)×(A,\mathscr{T_{in}})$, where $(\mathbb{R},ε)$ is the space given by real numbers with standard Euclidean topology, $A=\{a,b\}$ is a set with distinct points $a≠b$ and $\mathscr{T_{in}}$ is the trivial topology on our set $A$ that has only open sets $A$ and $∅$.

Want to show:

(c) Both subspaces are compact

(d) is the intersection of the subspaces compact?

I have already previously shown that $X$ has a path and is connected and path-connected but I'm stuck on how to start this. I have a definition that a subspace, say $Y$, will be compact iff every covering of $Y$ by sets open in a space, say $X$, contains a finite sub-collection covering $Y$. I have an example of applying to a general subspace but I'm not sure how to apply the definition to my specific $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$.

I think for (d) as well that for the intersection to be compact the space needs to be Hausdorff? But I'm also not sure how to show that if that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints for (c):

1. How does a non-empty open set in $X$ look like?
2. Now let $\mathcal{U}$ be an arbitrary open cover of $K_1$. Use the hint in 1. to deduce how $\mathcal{U}$ must look like.
3. Deduce that the compact interval $[0;1]$ must be contained in an open cover obtained from $\mathcal{U}$.
4. Build your finite subcover out of the finite cover obtained in 3.
5. Do the same for $K_2$.

Hints for (d):

1. What is $K=K_1\cap K_2$?
2. Can you find an open cover of $K$ which does not have a finite subcover?